# Undefined function 'etapar' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, simulink

Hello everyone i'm working on a project of pwm command using simulink,but i'm stuck in this error "Undefined function 'etapar' for input arguments of type 'cell'" any solutions please??

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE!. There is insufficient info in the question. Please copy and paste the *exact* error message into the question. Use the [edit] button to do that. Please also post a screenshot on the Simulink block diagram. Please also add to the question any code which is involved in the error.

Comment: With error messages it is always a good idea to [search it on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=simulink+matlab+Undefined+function+for+arguments+of+type+cell) to see if anyone else has encountered the same error.

Comment: The web search tells me that "*Two different ways to index cell arrays: `{}` curly braces refer to the cell contents, whereas `()` parentheses refer to the cells themselves.*". More information is required to know if this is applicable to your situation.